# Github page not rendering

Tags: github, github-pages

I have been trying to setup my Github pages: https://kasakh.github.io/index.html

Even though there is an index.html file at the [master location](https://github.com/kasakh/kasakh.github.io), I do not know why the page is not being rendered. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh I am just trying to load via kasakh.github.io or kasakh.github.io/index.html

Comment: Yes thats what i am saying, the problem is not with your code it may be something in there backend.You can contact them and ask for help if you can't find solution here https://github.com/contact :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your master location and opened the index.html file. It's HUGE! It's possible that there's a timeout happening. Try taking the page down to just the html and see if it renders. I'm sure it will :).

As far as all of the 12k lines, you can easily move them out into .js and .css files and link to them.

I copied your file down to my local box and tested it within Python's http.server commandlet. You have a link to a stylesheet on line 11740 that is throwing a 404 Error.

As far as moving all of the styles and scripts into their own files still stands. If you had everything in proper external files, this would have popped out at you very quickly.

Comment: but kasakh.github.io/untitled.html with the same code works fine; so 12k lines of code should not be problem

Comment: The error on line 11740 should have caused problem even in kasakh.github.io/untitled.html, which is not the case

Answer (score 0):

I got a mail saying that "The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

You have an error on line 3 of your `_config.yml` file."

I think there was an empty space, removing which fixed my problem.

Thank you everyone.